# What pixel sizes, should be used for website images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image

A seemingly simply question.  I have created a responsive website, with Bootstrap.  On one particular page, there are 4 columns, with equal widths.  In each column, an image is to be inserted.

In order to insert an image, as close to the column width as possible, would I simply divide 1024px by 3 as to establish the width of each of the 4 columns and then simply ensure the image is as close to the resultant column width as possible?

In doing so, the image will appear correctly on the larger 1024px screens, whilst also be scaled down on smaller screens.

Have I got this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you simply put a max width on your images to insure they are only as wide as their containing div's.

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Then as long as your images have the same dimensions they will each take up the same amount of space in each column.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I want to ensure that the images are the smallest size possible, before uploading them, as to keep the file size as low as possible.  Obviously, the image can only be as small as the largest screen size, as to prevent pixelation.

Comment: In that case bootstrap also includes gutters between columns which I believe is 30px.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: Whilst the 'total' gutter width, between columns is 30px, isn't each column space made up of 2 gutters, at 15px each?!